# NagiosXI: what does notification option "s" mean?

Tags: notifications, nagios

I can't seem to find documentation about the Notification Option type "s".  The context help for the form lists everything *except* the s option.  Anyone know what it means?  Or can you point me to the relevant documentation?

```
The Nagios XI Contact Management form shows these notification options:

Host Notification options:  d   u  r   f   s   n 
Service Notification options:  w   u   c   f   s   r   n
```

The Host notification options help popup describes the options as follows -- note that s is missing:

```
d = notify on DOWN host states,
u = notify on UNREACHABLE host states,
r = notify on host recoveries (UP states), and
f = notify when the host starts and stops flapping.
If you specify n (none) as an option, the contact will not receive any type of host notifications.
```

Similarly, the Service notification help popup describes the options as follows -- again, note that s is missing:

```
w = notify on WARNING service states,
u = notify on UNKNOWN service states,
c = notify on CRITICAL service states,
r = notify on service recoveries (OK states), and
f = notify when the service starts and stops flapping.
If you specify n (none) as an option, the contact will not receive any type of host notifications.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question on the Nagios Support Forum, and heard back from them:

```
s = send notifications when scheduled downtime starts and ends.

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html

We'll need to get that updated in the Nagios XI documentation, as
it appears missing, good find.
```

And the link they provided has the Notification Options definition:

```
notification_options:   

This directive is used to determine when notifications for the host should 
be sent out. Valid options are a combination of one or more of the following: 

d = send notifications on a DOWN state, 
u = send notifications on an UNREACHABLE state, 
r = send notifications on recoveries (OK state), 
f = send notifications when the host starts and stops flapping, and 
s = send notifications when scheduled downtime starts and ends. 

If you specify n (none) as an option, no host notifications will be sent out. 
If you do not specify any notification options, Nagios will assume that you 
want notifications to be sent out for all possible states. 

Example: 

If you specify d,r in this field, notifications will only be sent out when 
the host goes DOWN and when it recovers from a DOWN state.
```